# How we can force many mappers read one specific file (same data) in hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

i want to write a program that many mappers read one 1 file that 
is a graph and all do processing on that graph, that file is about 14 kb
if i run in normal way just one mapper will be mapped for that file
how i can do that?
Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the file in HDFS and read the file using HDFS API in the mapper function and do the processing on it. You can also try DistributedCache instead of putting the file in HDFS.

This scenario is also applicable when N simulations have to be done on a data set. The simulation factors will be the input to the map function and the actual data is read in the map function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but can i say in example 100 mapper run for that exact file that i stored and read that from HDFS ? how i can do this? there is a command conf.getInt("mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum", Number); but i dont think it can help me

Comment: The total # of mappers for a job equals to the InputSplits and cannot be controlled from the configuration parameters. So, you need to have 100 InputSlipts (these can be 100 files or 100 lines in a file) You can control the maximum number of map/reduce tasks to be run in ||el on a task tracker.